# Bilinear transformation from a closed half plane to outside the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to construct the bilinear transformation  which takes $Re(z)\geq 1$ to outside the open unit circle.  May I know how to proceed with the simpler way of doing it? I just want to know which are the three points  on the line $Re(z)=1$ and the circle $|z|=1$ to be considered to obtain the transformation?

Comment: A (possibly helpful) similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215813/42969

Comment: Thank you. I got it.